# dojoConfig 1.9 - dojo/html and dojo/date/stamp 404 (not found)

Tags: dojo

This is my first time using Dojo. My (striped down) dojoConfig looks like this:

```
var dojoConfig = {
    async: true,
    packages: [
        { name: "dojo", location: "js/dojo_1.9.0/dojo" },
        { name: "dijit", location: "js/dojo_1.9.0/dijit" },
        { name: "dojox", location: "js/dojo_1.9.0/dojox" }
    ]
};
```

My folder tree looks like this:

```
index.html
js
    dojo_1.9.0
        dijit
        dojo
        dojox
```

I'm using multiple modules, like this:

```
require(["dojo/html", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/_base/json", "dojo/dom", "dojo/query", "dojo/on", "dojo/request", "dojo/date/stamp", "dojo/domReady!"],
    function(html, domConstruct, win, dojo, dom, query, on, stamp, request){
    ...
});
```

All the modules are loaded normally except dojo/html and dojo/date/stamp. The error message shows the wrong path for both files (duplicating the 'location' link from 'packages'):

```
localhost/js/dojo_1.9.0/dojo/js/dojo_1.9.0/dojo/html.js
```

I tested this by copying an example from dojo/html reference using this same config. The result is identical - all the modules are loaded but the dojo/html. Any ideas?

Comment: The location of a package is relative to dojo.js if memory serves.

Comment: All the other modules are loaded normally, so the paths are surely right?

Answer (score 0):

Try set the dojoConfig this way:

```
var dojoConfig = {
async: true,
packages: [
    { name: "dojo", location: "/js/dojo_1.9.0/dojo" },
    { name: "dijit", location: "/js/dojo_1.9.0/dijit" },
    { name: "dojox", location: "/js/dojo_1.9.0/dojox" }
]
};
```

Using slash before set your path. To me solved this problem once.

Comment: My packages now looks like this: 
{ name: "dojo", location: "./" },
        { name: "dijit", location: "../dijit" },
        { name: "dojox", location: "../dojox" }, and it works, but I would like to know why.